# showing RecyclerView on fragment with data from Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having a problem with making a `RecycleView` in a fragment with data from Firebase. I expect the app to show the `RecycleView` after I clicked on a button to change from one fragment to the `RecycleView` fragment, but it does change the showed fragment but it does not show anything.

I know there are plenty of questions like this but I don't seem to find the correct solution to this problem.

I've made everything needed for a Firebase RecyclerView, and also tried to build it inside an activity instead fragment and it did work, but not with the fragment. 
I've tried to initialize the adapter and recyclerview inside the onCreateView method, onActivityCreated, and onViewCreated method and none of them seem to be working.

Here's my fragment code:

```
private KidAdapter adapter;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;

Button button;
View view;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.uangsaku_menu_fragment, container, false);
    button = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);

    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    setUpRecyclerView();

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v.getId() == R.id.btn_add){
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Register.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}

public void setUpRecyclerView(){
    Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("kids");

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<kidData> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<kidData>()
            .setQuery(query, kidData.class)
            .build();

    adapter = new KidAdapter(options);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (adapter != null) {
        adapter.startListening();
    }

}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (adapter != null) {
        adapter.stopListening();
    }

}
```

}

The adapter class

```
public class KidAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<kidData, KidAdapter.KidViewHolder> {

public KidAdapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<kidData> options) {
    super(options);
}

@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull KidViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull kidData model) {
    holder.nama.setText(model.getKidName());
    holder.balance.setText(model.getKidBalance());
    holder.limit.setText("Limit: "+model.getKidLimit());
    holder.spending.setText("Spending xxx.xxx");
}

@NonNull
@Override
public KidViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.kids_card,
            viewGroup, false);
    return new KidViewHolder(v);
}

public class KidViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView nama, balance, limit, spending;
    public KidViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        nama = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_nama);
        balance = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_balance);
        limit = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_dailylimit);
        spending = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_dailyspending);
    }
}
```

}

The kidData model class

```
public class kidData {
String kidName, kidEmail, kidDoB, kidLimit, kidBalance;

public kidData(){

}

public kidData(String kidName, String kidEmail, String kidDoB, String kidLimit, String kidBalance) {
    this.kidName = kidName;
    this.kidEmail = kidEmail;
    this.kidDoB = kidDoB;
    this.kidLimit = kidLimit;
    this.kidBalance = kidBalance;
}

public String getKidName() {
    return kidName;
}

public String getKidEmail() {
    return kidEmail;
}

public String getKidDoB() {
    return kidDoB;
}

public String getKidLimit() {
    return kidLimit;
}

public String getKidBalance() {
    return kidBalance;
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried to remove `recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);`? Does it work without it?

Comment: it works wow never though it would be this simple :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem in your code is the use of the following line of code:

```
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

And this is because when using the latest version of `Firebase-UI` library, there is no need to set the size of the `RecyclerView` as fixed. The solution for solving this problem is to simply remove/comment the above line of code. That's it!