# how to solve and connect the spinner with recyclerView issue

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, android-spinner

I have one problem with spinner and the recyclerView when selecting the number from Spinner array it's not retrieve from the firebase database.
and if I put a number manually in a query in orderBy it works and retrieves the data from firebase.

```
query = firestore.collection("ahmed").orderBy( "04", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);
```

Needs : When selecting from the spinner (number) and then String monthSelect change automatically in query and retrieve the data from firebase.

The code is :

```
 public class spinnerMonthly extends Fragment {


View view;
appKey appKey;
infoKey infoKey;
FirebaseAuth auth;
FirebaseFirestore firestore;
RecyclerView mrecyclerView;
FirestoreRecyclerAdapter adapter1;
FirestoreRecyclerOptions<infoKey> options;
Spinner spinner;
String monthSelect = "01";
Query query;
String monthArr[] = {"01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12"};

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_month,container,false);


   auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
   firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
   btn_check = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_chk);
   spinner = view.findViewById(R.id.sp_month);
   mrecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.rec_spinner_list);
   userID = auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

   ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, monthArr);
   spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

   spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
       @Override
       public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
           switch (position){
               case 0:
                   monthSelect = "01";
                   Toast.makeText(getContext(),monthSelect , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   break;
               case 1:
                   monthSelect = "02";
                   Toast.makeText(getContext(),monthSelect , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   break;
               case 2:
                   monthSelect = "03";
                   Toast.makeText(getContext(),monthSelect , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   break;
               case 3:
                   monthSelect = "04";
                   Toast.makeText(getContext(),monthSelect , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   break;
               case 4:
                   monthSelect = "05";
                   Toast.makeText(getContext(),monthSelect , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   break;
               case 5:
                   monthSelect = "06";
                   Toast.makeText(getContext(),monthSelect , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   break;
               case 6:
                   monthSelect = "07";
                   Toast.makeText(getContext(),monthSelect , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   break;
               case 7:
                   monthSelect = "08";
                   Toast.makeText(getContext(),monthSelect , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   break;
               case 8:
                   monthSelect = "09";
                   Toast.makeText(getContext(),monthSelect , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   break;
               case 9:
                   monthSelect = "10";
                   Toast.makeText(getContext(),monthSelect , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   break;
               case 10:
                   monthSelect = "11";
                   Toast.makeText(getContext(),monthSelect , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   break;
               case 11:
                   monthSelect = "12";
                   Toast.makeText(getContext(),monthSelect , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   break;
           }
       }

       @Override
       public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

       }
   });

    query = firestore.collection("ahmed").orderBy( monthSelect , Query.Direction.DESCENDING);

    options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<infoKey>()
            .setQuery(query, infoKey.class)
            .build();

    adapter1 = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<infoKey, ViewHolder>(options) {
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull infoKey model) {
            holder.details.setText(model.getDetails());
            holder.pricee.setText(model.getPricee());
            holder.currentDate.setText(model.getCurrentDate());
            if (model.getType().equals("input")) {
                holder.type.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_input);
            } else {
                holder.type.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_output);
            }


        }
    };

    mrecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mrecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    mrecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter1);

    return view;
}

private class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

private TextView currentDate;
private TextView pricee;
private TextView details;
private ImageView type;

public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    currentDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dateTV);
    pricee = itemView.findViewById(R.id.priceeTV);
    details = itemView.findViewById(R.id.detailsTV);
    type = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_status);
}
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    adapter1.startListening();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    adapter1.stopListening();
}
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that "monthSelect" actually holds the correct value?

Comment: yes ... there's another way to holds and listen to query ?

Comment: That's the most common way. Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54458874/showing-recyclerview-on-fragment-with-data-from-firebase/54459564#54459564)?